# Inflate decompression operation success without processing complete compressed data

Tags: c, compression, deflate, inflate

I am using Software Inflate methods ( Raw deflate method and not GZIP/ZLIB variants )for decompression operations.

Strangely, I noticed the following obseravations

1.) When I pass in a single compressed buffer ( avail_in and next_in fields )as a source data and a single destination buffer ( avail_out and next_out )for decompression output , inflate decompression operations succeeded with Z_STREAM_END positive status. I also compared this with original uncompressed data and its a match.

2.) However, when I split the compressed data in two buffers , 1 buffer with compressed data minus one bytes  ( compressed data size -1 ), second buffer with size 1 byte and a single destination buffer of size that of original uncompressed length, inflate decompression operation succeeded with Z_OK positive status filling out my complete destination buffer ( avail_out = 0 and total_out = original uncompressed size ). I also compared this with original uncompressed data and its a match.

I am highly confused on why inflate() operation succeeded to produce all of the original data without processing a second source buffer.? Is this expected behavior with inflate operation ?

3.) I also tried above 2 method by splitting source data in 2 buffers where last buffer is of length 2 bytes and 1 source buffers size is compressed data -2 and with a single dest buffer.Saw the same similar behavior as that of 2.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is expected.

The inflated data is a stream of variable-bitlength codes, concatenated together into the byte stream. The individual code units are not byte-aligned, and the compressed stream generally does not end on a byte boundary. So the last byte of the compressed stream is likely to have a few unused bits.

The compressed stream does not store its length. Instead, one of the code units is used as an end of stream indicator. The code units themselves are essentially Huffman codes, so the most common ones are the shortest. The end-of-stream indicator only appears once in the stream, so its code is likely to be more than 8 bits.

So it's guaranteed that the last byte in the compressed stream only contains the end-of-stream indicator, and it is highly likely that the end-of-stream indicator also occupied the entire second-last byte, as well as a few bits of the third-last byte. (I'm pretty sure that the code length is limited to 16 bits, but I didn't check the reference materials.)

Each code unit corresponds to one or more bytes in the original message, and these bytes can be regenerated without referring to the next code unit. If you decompress up to the code unit which precedes the end-of-stream, you have decompressed the entire file; the only thing that the end-of-stream indicator tells you is that you are done.

Comment: Thanks A lot. So do you mean there is no fixed size end of steam markers for deflate (inflate ) decompression algorithm. ?

Comment: @user3555115: technically, there are three kinds of data blocks: uncompressed, compressed with a fixed huffman code, compressed with a dynamically computed huffnan code. Most blocks are of the third type. In that case, the length of code items will vary from block to block.